# Almacenando registros en un campo por medio de un array - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos! Estoy intentando almacenar las subopciones de respuesta de redes sociales, tal como se ven en la imagen, sin embargo por alguna razón no se esta almacenando, el servidor no registra el almacenamiento del campo "subrespondent", la idea, es que tome las opciones seleccionadas en las casillas y las meta en un solo array que se almacenaran dentro del campo "subrespondent", probablemente, a pesar de haber establecido el array, creo que hace falta algo para unir los datos y almacenarlos en el campo, agradezco su ayuda

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: respondent, local: true) do |form| %>
    <ol>
        <% @survey.questions.each do |q| %>
            <li>
                <%= form.fields_for :answers do |a| %>
                    <%= q.title %>
                    <ol type="none">
                    <% q.question_options.each do |qo| %>
                        <li>
                            <%= a.radio_button :response, qo.id %> 
                            <%= a.label :response, qo.title %>
                            <%= a.hidden_field :question_id, value: q.id %>              
                            <ol type="none">
                                <% qo.sub_question_options.each do |sqo| %>
                                    <li>
                                        <%= a.check_box :subresponse, value: sqo.id %> 
                                        <%= a.label :subresponse, sqo.title %>
                                        <%= a.hidden_field :question_option_id, value: sqo.id %>
                                    </li>
                                <% end %>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                    </ol>
                <% end %>          
            </li>
        <% end %>  
    </ol>      
<% end %>
```

**respondents_controller.rb**

```
class RespondentsController < ApplicationController

    def new
       @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey])
       @respondent = Respondent.new
       @respondent.answers.build
    end

    def respondent_params
      params.require(:respondent).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :survey_id, answers_attributes: [:id, :response, :subresponse, :question_id, :question_option_id, :respondent_id])
    end

end
```

**create_answer.rb**

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.text :response
      t.text :subresponse, array: true, default: []
      t.references :question, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :question_option_id, foreign_key: true
      t.references :respondent, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Estructura general del proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que con "subrespondent" te refieres a "subresponse".
No estoy seguro, pero creo que tu error es porque no estás aceptando el parámetro subresponse como un arreglo:

```
  def respondent_params
    params.require(:respondent).permit(
      :name, :email, :phone, :survey_id, answers_attributes: [
        :id, :response, :question_id, :question_option_id, :respondent_id, 
        subresponse: []
      ]
    )
  end
```

Además como estás usando tu checkbox [no es la forma correcta](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box). Prueba con:

```
<%= a.check_box :subresponse, {multiple: true}, sqo.id, nil%>
```

`sqo.id` define el valor cuando va checked y `nil` para cuando va unchecked. Si no defines esto, rails usará por defecto unos y ceros para indicar si va checked/unchecked.
E insisto, si esto no lo resuelve, agrega la definición de tu método y muestra el log de cuando realizas el request que no te guarda la información.

Comment: Saludos Alter! Ya esta almacenando lo cual es bueno! con lo unico que solo me esta almacenando esto `["0", "1", "0", "1", "0"]`, y no son los ids correctos de los sub_questions_options, y me los almacena si agrego multiple: true al campo, es decir, `<%= a.check_box :subresponse, value: sqo.id, multiple: true %>` sin embargo al eliminar el multiple: true no almacena nada, no se si habra una mejor forma de anidar los check_box y almacene los datos correctos

Comment: @HectorHernandez la manera en que llamas a multiple no es la correcta, revisa mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: Excelente Alter!! Una ultima pregunta Alter, actualmente estoy almacenando los ids, de cada subrespuesta, de que forma, puedo llamar a la vista los nombres de esos ids?

Comment: Alter, he actualizado el post, y he puesto un diagrama general del proyecto junto con los campos necesarios, y las relaciones respectivas, esto para tener un mejor panorama del proyecto, ahorita solo necesito que los ids, de esos arrays, muestren sus title